# Follow external database from Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, migration

Is it possible to configure a Postgres 9.1 database running in EC2 to be the source for a Heroku Postgres follower database? In other words:

```
$ heroku config:set MY_DATABASE_URL=postgres://my_user:my_pass@my_ec2_server:5432/my_db
$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:ronin --follow MY_DATABASE_URL
```

What settings would be required on the source database to allow for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, sorry, not possible. We are only able to fork or follow databases that we provision.