# Is it possible to have a Heroku Postgres DB replicate down to a slave DB on my laptop?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, replication

I'd like to have my master Postgres DB, which is is hosted on Heroku, replicate down to a slave DB on my laptop.  Is this possible?

Heroku's documentation talks about both master and slave hosted within Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases

Someone else asked whether it's possible to have the master outside Heroku and a slave inside Heroku (it's not):
[Follow external database from Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182899/follow-external-database-from-heroku)

I haven't seen an answer for the reverse -- having the master in Heroku and the slave outside.

Why do I want this?  To speed up development.  With my app running locally and the DB in the cloud, the round-trip is long so data access is slow.  Most data access is read-only.  If I could have a local slave, it would speed things up significantly.

Related: what if my laptop is disconnected for a while?  Would that cause problems for the master?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot make a follower (slave) outside of the Heroku network – followers need superuser access to create, which Heroku Postgres doesn't provide you, so you are limited to running a follower on Heroku.

If you want to pull down a copy locally for use/inspection, you can do so with pgbackups: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend the program [Parity](https://github.com/thoughtbot/parity) for this.

It copies down the last Heroku backup to your local machine with a nice command line interface:

`development restore production`

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather just pull the production database's contents from Heroku every now and then.

```
$ heroku db:pull
```

You can speed that up with a rake task.

```
# lib/tasks/deployment.rake
namespace :production do
  desc 'Pull the production DB to the local env'
  task :pull_db do
    puts   'Pulling PRODUCTION db to local...'
    system 'heroku db:pull --remote MY_REMOTE_NAME --confirm MY_APP_NAME'
    puts   'Pulled production db to local'
  end
end
```

You can call `rake production:pull_db` to overwrite your local development database.

Comment: Don't use `db:pull`. It's been removed from the documentation (for Heroku Postgres). Use `pgbackups` and download a copy from there, or use `pg_dump` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've been using this for a while and it might not be the most current way any more.