# Is it possible to have a Heroku Postgres DB replicate from a master DB on my laptop? Version 9.6 or 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'd like to have my slave Postgres DB, which is is hosted on Heroku, replicate from a master DB on my laptop. Is this possible?  With version 9.6 or 9.4

I read the question: [Follow external database from Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182899/follow-external-database-from-heroku)
 but it was for version 9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you speak of streaming replication, then it is not possible and will never be I think. Heroku shares DATABASE - not cluster and streaming replication would require the whole cluster and REPLICATION role access.

Comment: thank you . This answers my question. Please confirm if you know one online platform I can use to perform Streaming Replication to a local PostgreSQL DB.

Comment: I doubt there would be any. streaming replication would mean dedicated instance just for yo.